# get index of boolean values in pandas - python

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, boolean

```
a=pd.DataFrame({'a1':[1,2,3,4],'a2':[5,6,7,8]})
c=pd.DataFrame({'c1':[True,False,True,True],'c2':[True,False,False,True]})
```

How can I get the index of the elements in columns `a1` and `a2` which are `True` in columns `c1` and `c2` respectively?

The index of `a1` should be `[0,2,3]` and the index of `a2` `[0,3]`. The result could be a list of indexes like `[[0,2,3],[0,3]]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need [`where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html):

```
c.columns = a.columns
df1 = a.where(c)
idx = [df1[x].dropna().index.tolist() for x in df1]
print (idx)
[[0, 2, 3], [0, 3]]
```

Another solution:

```
c.columns = a.columns
idx = list(a.where(c).stack().reset_index()
            .groupby('level_1')['level_0'].apply(list))
print (idx)
[[0, 2, 3], [0, 3]]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Isn't there a way to do this without having to specify each column explicitly? My dataframe has many columns like a1,a2,a3,etc.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't clear what you want exactly.

This is an approach using `stack`

```
a.stack().index[c.stack().values].to_series()

0  a1    (0, a1)
   a2    (0, a2)
2  a1    (2, a1)
3  a1    (3, a1)
   a2    (3, a2)
dtype: object
```

If you want just the list of index values

```
a.index.values[c.values.any(1)]

array([0, 2, 3])
```